# Mysql Dump RDS Trough Ec2 Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I'm trying to download a sql dump of my MySQL database in RDS through my local terminal.  I have security groups setup so that only my ec2 instances can access this RDS database.  Is there a way to run the mysqldump command all in one line w/o having to ssh into the Ec2 box > run command there > then scp the dump out to my local machine?

Command I normally run inside ec2 instance is

```
mysqldump DBNAME -h RDSURL -u USERNAME -p -P PORT > ~/dump.sql
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by setting up port forwarding per Mark B's advice.  In one terminal window I did

```
 ssh -N -L 1234:RDSURL:PORT EC2USER@EC2URL -i LOCALPEMKEY
```

Then in 2nd terminal window I did

```
 mysqldump DBNAME -h 127.0.0.1 -u USERNAME -p -P 1234 > ~/dump.sql
```

Worked like a charm.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Mark B.